# How do many-body fermionic operators transform under coordinate transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, fermions, many-body

In non-relaivistic many-body physics, sometimes called second quantisation, fermionic fields $\psi(x)$ obey the anti-commuation relations

$$ \{ \psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y) \} = \delta(x-y), \quad \{ \psi(x),\psi(y) \} = \{ \psi(x)^\dagger , \psi(y)^\dagger \} = 0$$

and we interpret $|x\rangle = \psi^\dagger(x) |0\rangle$ as a particle located at the position $x$, where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum annihilated by all annihilation operators. These operators are "spinless" fermions as they do not have any internal degrees of freedom (they are one component objects).

### My question

How do these fields transform under coordinate transformations? In relativistic physics, we would define the field as living in a spinor or tensor representation etc., but here I am interested in **non-relativistic physics** and I have not been able to find a discussion in many-body literature of how fields transform. I see two ways in which the fields could transform:

1. The obvious way: $\psi(x) \rightarrow \tilde{\psi}(y) = \psi(x(y))$. This gives us the commutation relation
   $$ \{ \tilde{\psi}(y_1),\tilde{\psi}^\dagger(y_2)\} = \{\psi(x(y_1),\psi^\dagger(x(y_2))\} = \delta(x(y_1)-x(y_2))=\frac{\delta(y_1-y_2)}{|\partial x/\partial y|}$$ This gives us the commutation relation with the Dirac delta function of the new coordinate system which picks up a Jacobian.
2. The less obvious way: $\psi(x) \rightarrow \tilde{\psi}(y) = \sqrt{|\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}|}\psi(x(y))$. With this definition, we have the commuation relation $$ \{ \tilde{\psi}(y_1),\tilde{\psi}^\dagger(y_2) \} = \delta(y_1-y_2)$$ where now the Jacobian factor of the Dirac delta is cancelled by how the field transformation is defined. In this way, the anti-commutation relations remain invariant.

My motivation for these definitions was that under a change of coordinates, the field must obey the correct anti-commutation relations, however I have not seen any literature disussing this. So again, my question is: how do many-body fermionic operators transform under coordinate transformations?

Comment: In fact exactly the same issue arises even in relativistic theories when you consider e.g. transformation of scalar fields under conformal coordinate maps. There one has to do something like your option (2) to keep action invariant (which under canonical quantization means the commutation relations remain the same).